# Can Sphinx match against terms or phrases that are similar to the provided search params?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, full-text-search, sphinx

I've got MySQL free-text search up and running in my rails app.

If I search for 'regular guitar cable' I get back 'guitar' and 'cable', which is what I want.

Now I've installed Sphinx and the thinking-sphinx gem, and I've found that a search for 'regular guitar cable' doesn't return any results at all. What's worse is that if I search for 'guitars' I get nothing! Instead I'm finding that I have to search for 'guitar' instead i.e. I need to enter the exact term.

This is problematic because very few of my users will search for 'guitar' and instead it's more likely that they will search for 'red guitar' or 'cheap guitar' and I need sphinx to be a bit smarter.

How can I make it do what I want without having to add every single adjective
 in the english dictionary to a stop-word file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following resolved my problem!

```
Product.search "\"#{search_text}\"/1"
```

The `/1` at the end makes it work, and it's called the **Quorum operator**.